# How can I use math symbols in Ubuntu?

Tags: unicode

I tried to use Mathematics symbols in web to search a formula directly,but I don't know how to insert mathematics symbols?

I can't find any Mathematics options in Ubuntu's Character Map application,

[image: Imgur]

Comment: which program(s) do you want to insert symbols into?

Comment: to answer a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/) on Meta.MathSE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Use CharacterMap

With Character Map, you can select a large range of non-standard and international characters **(including math symbol which you need)** to put in your documents.

No need to install it, because it was part of the default ubuntu installtion.

## How to launch ?

If you using **gnome**, go to Accessories --> Character Map

If you using **unity**, search "Character Map" in dash.

Or, run following command on terminal :

```
gucharmap
```

In Character Map menu, View > By Unicode Block. Then select "mathematical operators" on left sidebar.

[image]

Double click any symbol to copy.

Comment: but there is no Mathematical...option in character map,I would like to add screen shot but I don't know how to add!

Comment: @AnilKrishna what symbol do you want to insert ?

Comment: integral and differential symbols also to write math equations @Liso

Comment: @Ravan: Go to View Menu (at the top of the window) and choose *By Unicode Block* option. It works for me. It's totally unintuitive, but it works. It must be some Ubuntu programmer sense of humor.

Comment: If `gucharmap` is missing, it is possible to install it simply using `sudo apt-get install gucharmap`

Answer (score 0):

Maths SE uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) so you can add mathematical symbols etc without needing to insert symbols 
- you can use it as covered [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

N.B. If you want help using MathSE you probably should ask [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/).